# How to create fake REST server based on RAML API specification and XML Data?

Tags: xml, api, rest, raml

I wrote the API specification using RAML. The responses are defined by XML Schemas and they have examples of XML body. Now I need to mock up the server based on my specification to test the API. Unfortunately the most of mockers support only JSON data and I can't find anything that may be used with XML data. I have tested:

- [LocalAPI](https://github.com/isaacloud/local-api)
- [raml-mocker-server](https://github.com/dmitrisweb/raml-mocker-server)
- [raml-server](https://github.com/farolfo/raml-server)

and they are useless with my XML responses defined in RAML. Is there anything else that I can check?